# Rails Project automatically deleted after rake db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I was working on Nitrous.io on a Rails Project.

I have created a new branch and then after some coding , I reset the database with
 rake db:reset.

After this action my Projects folders were automatically deleted.

Someone could help me understand what is wrong on my command?

Comment: what version of rails were you using?

Answer (score 0):

`db:reset` will do exactly as described - it will "reset" the database.  So `db:reset` is the same as executing the following commands: `db:drop` (which will drop/delete all entries in the database) + `db:setup`

Comment: Ok and this what I whant, drop the database and create a new one. The problem is that it also deleted my project folder with all .rb files

Comment: Honestly none of the `db` commands will erase any of your profiles files so there must be some other cause for the project files being deleted.  Please update your question with a list of all commands that you ran before the files vanished (both project specific and command-line specific).

Comment: I right click on one of the migration files and deleted it. Then i ran the rake command and I saw the entire folder and subfolders disappear.

Comment: Sounds like you right-clicked on a folder and deleted the project folder instead of deleting one file.  Maybe it's still in your trash bin?  To get files that are deleted you can use tools like undelete or http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/

Comment: Max I am using the nitrous.io website , unfortunally no trash bin, and i also suppose the problem is due a bug on their interface

Answer (score 0):

I somehow doubt it that `rake db:reset` deletes your .rb files. Must be something else. Maybe you messed up with git?

```
rake db:reset
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

works just fine, normally.

Comment: I also doubt that rake db:reset was the problem. But I would like to know what could cause the problem. Nitrous support ask me to open a question here and i did it.